Dynamically referencing worksheets to dynamically fill a table based on a condition
Here is a dummy worksheet with the file structure:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RJZW3_lKJkvumcOuSoGLQnZG8NcaTfkJfVm4obTcSq4/edit?usp=sharing
I have a dropdown of language names in Sheet1, an empty table, and a column containing the names of all the sheets in the current document.
I want to dynamically fill the table in Sheet1 with data from the other sheets based on the language selected on the dropdown.
For example, if the user selects "English" from the dropdown, the table on Sheet1 will be dynamically filled with all the School Names where we have students who speak the selected language, and in each row, we'll have the School Name, the student's Age, Name and the Language spoken (which matches the one from the dropdown).
I can't provide an example of what I have already tried because everything I tried failed miserably, I apologize.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!


Here's one approach you may test out:
=let(Σ,tocol(,1), reduce(Σ,tocol(F2:F,1),lambda(a,c,vstack(if(iserr(+a),Σ,a),let(Λ,filter(choosecols(indirect(c&"!A4:C"),3,2,1),if(B1="",indirect(c&"!A4:A")<>"",indirect(c&"!B4:B")=B1)),
 Δ,indirect(C&"!A1"), if(isna(Λ),Σ,hstack(wrapcols(Δ,rows(Λ),Δ),Λ)))))))



That worked perfectly, thank you so much for such an elegant solution, you're a wizard! Thanks for taking the time to help me with that. Sending you some love!

Use QUERY and VSTACK
Use VSTACK and HSTACK to stack all data from multiple sheets and then use QUERY to filter the data.

=QUERY(VSTACK(IFERROR(HSTACK(Sheet2!A1, Sheet2!A4:C8),Sheet2!A1),IFERROR(HSTACK(Sheet3!A1,
Sheet3!A4:C8),Sheet3!A1),IFERROR(HSTACK(Sheet4!A1,
Sheet4!A4:C8),Sheet4!A1)),"SELECT Col1, Col4, Col3, Col2 WHERE Col3 =
'"&B1&"'")

Output:

References:

VSTACK
HSTACK
QUERY


Thank you for taking the time to tackle my problem! I went with the solution from the other comment, as ti was more flexible for the kind of document I'm dealing with, but I really appreciate your time and work. Wishing you a wonderful weekend ahead!
